# Soundpool is not playing any sound

Tags: java, android, android-studio, soundpool

Im trying to make soundpool work because I need to use it for a prodject. The problem is that it's not playing any sound. Im just trying to play a test sound to see if it works. Hope someone can see what im doing wrong here.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SoundPool soundPool;
int game_over;

@Override
protected void onCreate(
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes
                .Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ASSISTANCE_SONIFICATION)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .build();
        soundPool = new SoundPool
                .Builder()
                .setMaxStreams(4)
                .setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes)
                .build();
    }
    
    game_over = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.test, 1);
    soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
            soundPool.play(game_over, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1f);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set up `setOnLoadCompleteListener` BEFORE `load` call (which should use `sampleId`, as `game_over` may be not assigned yet)

```
soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
        soundPool.play(sampleId, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1f);
    }
});
game_over = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.test, 1);
```

afaik all `load` methods of `SoundPool` are synchronous -  they are returning ID of already loaded audio file. setting `OnLoadCompleteListener` AFTER loading audio will cause no call for this listener, as there is nothing more to load

Comment: Thats true, missed that thing. But it did not play any thing.

Comment: check volume level set on device (for every "category") and ensure that [`play`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool#play(int,%20float,%20float,%20int,%20int,%20float)) method returns non-0 value (same as `load`)

Comment: Did just try that. The play method returns 1 so it should be playing.

Comment: ensure volume level, maybe use another test file... also try with different `setUsage` flags. don't have any other clues...

Comment: It's working on the emulator but not on my phone

Answer (score 0):

This code is now working. Why it was not playing on my phone was because it was using the system volume and not the music volume. Hope this will help someone else in the future.